# Column default value via query execution

Tags: sql, oracle, audit

I have an audit table which keeps track of user updating the data. 
There are 2 ways of updating the data, first via GUI where logged in user will be updated in audit table. Second is by executing sql queries, now in this case i want to populate logged in DB user in Audit table. I want to achieve this by setting default value for audit user column by executing the query `Select user from dual`

Is it possible in oracle to set default value of a column to result of a query output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a query, just use the keyword `user`

```
create table audit_table
(
  ... other columns ....
  changed_when timestamp   default current_timestamp not null, 
  changed_by   varchar(30) default user              not null
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But do you know if its possible to execute a query for default value setting?

Comment: @Lokesh: no, that's not possible. You can however write a function that does this and then use the function as the default value.